# How to append strings to a vector from a for loop?

Tags: r, list, append

I got a data frame that has a column with names separated by commas, I want to create a vector that includes each name independently inside but my solution didn't work. Need help with it.

```
library(tidyverse)

cast <- netflix_titles$cast
names <- c()
for(i in cast){
  splitted <- strsplit(i, ",")
  for(act in splitted){
    append(names, act)
  }
}
```

rows are in this format

> "Jesse Eisenberg, Woody Harrelson, Emma Stone, Abigail Breslin, Amber Heard, Bill Murray, Derek Graf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a vector of names with `unlist(strsplit())`. `strsplit` itself returns a list which you can turn into an atomic vector with `unlist`.

```r
unlist(strsplit("Jesse Eisenberg, Woody Harrelson, Emma Stone, Abigail Breslin, Amber Heard, Bill Murray, Derek Graf", ", "))

#> [1] "Jesse Eisenberg" "Woody Harrelson" "Emma Stone"      "Abigail Breslin"
#> [5] "Amber Heard"     "Bill Murray"     "Derek Graf"
```

Hence, you can completely remove the `for` loop if you add `unlist()`.

You can even do it for the whole column in the data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(cast = c(
  "Jesse Eisenberg, Woody Harrelson, Emma Stone, Abigail Breslin, Amber Heard, Bill Murray, Derek Graf",
  "Bruce Willis, Matt Damon, Brad Pitt"
))

unlist(strsplit(df$cast, ", "))

#> [1] "Jesse Eisenberg" "Woody Harrelson" "Emma Stone"      "Abigail Breslin"
#> [5] "Amber Heard"     "Bill Murray"     "Derek Graf"      "Bruce Willis"   
#> [9] "Matt Damon"      "Brad Pitt"
```